# How to setup fetchmail for mu4e?

Tags: mu4e, email

Disclaimer: I am not very well-versed about how email servers and email clients work.

I have been lately looking into setting up email on my Emacs. I decided that I'll use mu4e. If I understand correctly, one has to setup their maildir before they can get mu4e. For that, I decided to use fetchmail. I installed it using apt and now have some questions about setting it up properly. If I understand one has to put up a `~/.fetchmailrc`.

Reading the manual, this was the simplest configs I could find for a single user.

```
poll <server address> proto <protocol, e. g., pop3> port <number>
     user <email address> with pass "<password>" is "<local machine username>" here keep
```

So is that setup it for setting up this maildir I keep reading about? Btw, if someone could tell me where this directory is, that'll be nice. The manual for `fetchmail` also says:

```
Note that although there are password declarations in a  good  many  of
the  examples below, this is mainly for illustrative purposes.  We rec‐
ommend stashing account/password pairs in your $HOME/.netrc file, where
they  can  be  used  not just by fetchmail but by ftp(1) and other pro‐
grams.
```

So this makes me a little nervous. Are those configs safe? Will the fetchmail encrypt the communication that downloads the mails and will it encrypt the password when it sends it to the server or will I have to setup some other options to do that properly?

Do I also have to configure other options to keep the directory structure that the Microsoft account has? Like will the mail in maildir be downloaded as folders for example inbox, sent, spam etc.

Basically, could someone who uses fetchmail with mu4e show us how to configure fetchmail for it? All of this still only configures downloading the mail. How could I set up sending mail?

Comment: This is probably off-topic for this site, since it's mostly about fetchmail configuration. Googling for "fetchmail tutorial" shows multiple hits with [this one](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/clients/using-fetchmail-to-retrieve-email/) at the top. Once you have fetchmail properly configured and tested with a command line client (e.g. mailx) or a TUI client (e.g. mutt), then you can do the setup with mu4e, which I imagine would be very easy (but I really don't know: I don't use mu4e). It's only the last part that's relevant to this site.

Comment: Non of the online articles quite answer the questions I am asking. This may not be related directly to this site but I know mu4e is popular among emacs' users so I imagined that one of those users may have fetchmail figured out.